# Is it possible to write a mapreduce program that takes input from hdfs and writes output to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, connector

Hi guys i m new to mongodb and hadoop.i want to write a mapreduce program that reads input from hdfs and writes its output mongodb.i also tried mongo-hadoop connector but while using connector i dont know how to write mapreduce that takes input from hdfs .i am only able to write mapreduce that uses mongodb for both input and output.it would be more help full if i was able to get sample codes or any reference

-Thankyou

Comment: Please show some effort

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB as both a source and destination for data. So yes, you can load data from HDFS into Mongo using the MongoDB Hadoop connector http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/

You can find examples in their github repository https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/master/examples

Comment: thanx for your answer .Examples in the link takes input also from mongodb but what i need is that input should be taken from hdfs and not from mongodb .is there is any sample code or reference for it  -thank you